# HBase FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_NONE functionality

Tags: row, filtering, hbase

I have multiple row filters added to a hierarchy of FilterLists that allows me to filter only what I need from the HBase table, something like the following:

```
FilterList list = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);
FilterList uidList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
if(term.length()>longSize){
    long highValue = Long.parseLong(term.substring(longSize));
    uidList.addFilter(new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL,
                            new BinaryComparator(Bytes.add(prefix, Bytes.toBytes(addLongPadding(lowValue))))));
    uidList.addFilter(new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL,
                            new BinaryComparator(Bytes.add(prefix, Bytes.toBytes(addLongPadding(highValue))))));
} else
    uidList.addFilter(new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
                            new BinaryComparator(Bytes.add(prefix, Bytes.toBytes(addLongPadding(lowValue))))));
list.addFilter(uidList);
```

This is just an example, there are a lot more filters for particular cases added in `list`. Is there a way in which I can use the `FilterList` operators such that I can negate a filter? for this example I would need to filter all the rows that are not in between the `lowValue` and `highValue` and that for the else branch are `NOT_EQUAL` to my value(`lowValue == highValue`).

I know that the operators are based on `NAND` and `NOR` so tehnically it could be possible, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no between operator for the hbase columns. If you want those type of filters, you need to write on yourself according to your requirement.

Check this code snippet:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> between(String tableName,String colFamilyName, String [] colName,String betweenColName,String lowerValue,String upperValue)
{
    ResultScanner rs=null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Result res = null;
    try
    {
        HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        SingleColumnValueFilter singleColumnValueFilterA = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
                Bytes.toBytes(colFamilyName), Bytes.toBytes(betweenColName), CompareOp.GREATER, Bytes.toBytes(lowerValue));
                singleColumnValueFilterA.setFilterIfMissing(true); 
        SingleColumnValueFilter singleColumnValueFilterB = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
                Bytes.toBytes(colFamilyName), Bytes.toBytes(betweenColName), CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(upperValue));
        singleColumnValueFilterB.setFilterIfMissing(true); 
        FilterList filter = new FilterList(Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL, Arrays.asList((Filter) singleColumnValueFilterA,
                singleColumnValueFilterB)); 
        scan.setFilter(filter); 
        rs = table.getScanner(scan);
        while((res=rs.next()) != null)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            String s = null;
            for(int j=0 ; j < colName.length ; j++)
            {
                byte[] obtainedRow = res.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(colFamilyName),Bytes.toBytes(colName[j]));
                s = Bytes.toString(obtainedRow);
                map.put(colName[j],s);
            }           
            al.add(map);
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception occured in retrieving data");
    }
    finally
    {
        rs.close();
    }
    return al;
}
```

Comment: The `setFilterIfMissing` is a nice trick to use in the `SingleColumnValueFilter`, to effectively negate the filter you write, but it's constrained to this type of filter, so it seems that so far for other types of filter you just have to write the oposite filter...